# Trying to make a discord bot that sends a random message at a random time, but I keep getting this error

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is my code:

```
import random
import discord
import asyncio

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

msg = ['msg1','msg2','msg3']

@bot.command()
async def test(message):
  while True:
    chance = random.randint(1,4)
    print(chance)
    if chance == 1:
      msj = random.choice(msg)
      await message.send(msj)
    time = random.randint(60,3600)
    print(time)
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
bot.loop.create_task(test("!test"))
```

And there is my error :

```
await message.send(msj)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I tried to do this thing using bot.event, using `await bot.send(channel, msj)`, but I get a similar error:

```
await bot.send(channel, msj)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are calling the function from somewhere other and give the paramter as `string`? Or you are somewhere before defining a variable message which is a string? But normally this should be right. Also, you can forget bot.send, this isn't possible as you can see in the docs (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#bot)

Comment: 1. You are essentially doing `"!test".send(msj)`   2. Maybe look at [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)

Comment: If I delete the ```bot.loop.create_task(test("!test"))``` part, the error will be gone and my program will work, but I saw that after night, or some time after I close the program, it will stop working. (I already have it on uptimerobot.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ctx instead of message and then do: `await ctx.message.channel.send(msg)`

Comment: try this then: `await ctx.message.channel.send(msg)` I messed up with the original answer sorry.